# eliminate a variable for an accumulation operation

Tags: javascript

The following code produces the desired result but is there a way to refactor it to eliminate the `accumulator` variable?

```js
const data = [
  { id: "428", date: "2017-01-24" },
  { id: "526", date: "2022-01-01" },
  { id: "428", name: "George" },
  { id: "526", name: "Sam" },
  { id: "827", name: "Dan" }
];

const accumulator = {};

data.forEach(o => {
  accumulator[o.id] = { ...accumulator[o.id] , ...o } || o;
});

console.log(accumulator);
```

Comment: There's a built-in method already, `reduce`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `|| o` part doesn’t make sense (objects are always truthy), and the repeated spread can become a serious performance trap. It’s also good practice to start with `Object.create(null)` when using an object as a map to avoid keys colliding with things on `Object.prototype` (even though it looks like you have numeric keys for the moment).

So, let’s restart from this more efficient and reliable version:

```js
const data = [
  { id: "428", date: "2017-01-24" },
  { id: "526", date: "2022-01-01" },
  { id: "428", name: "George" },
  { id: "526", name: "Sam" },
  { id: "827", name: "Dan" }
];

const accumulator = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(o => {
  Object.assign(accumulator[o.id] ??= {}, o);
});

console.log(accumulator);
```

With that in mind, here’s how you would use `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
const data = [
  { id: "428", date: "2017-01-24" },
  { id: "526", date: "2022-01-01" },
  { id: "428", name: "George" },
  { id: "526", name: "Sam" },
  { id: "827", name: "Dan" }
];

const accumulator = data.reduce(
  (accumulator, o) => {
    Object.assign(accumulator[o.id] ??= {}, o);
    return accumulator;
  },
  Object.create(null)
);

console.log(accumulator);
```

Comment: Can you convert these into runnable code snippets?  I tried the code in my sandbox but am not getting a result that matched my original output.

Comment: @knot22: Ah, sorry, I jumped the gun on `Object.assign`’s convenient return value. The first snippet should be equivalent, though.

Comment: Thanks.  Got it to work now.  Can you explain how `Object.assign(accumulator[o.id] ??= {}, o);` works?

Comment: @knot22: `accumulator[o.id] ??= {}` evaluates to `accumulator[o.id]` if it’s defined, and otherwise assigns a new empty object to `accumulator[o.id]` and evaluates to that. The rest is [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Answer (score 1):

The built-in method [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) already does this. Pass the accumulator as the second argument. The first argument in the callback is the accumulated value. The second is the current object in this iteration. Return value of callback is passed to next iteration as the accumulated value.

```js
const data = [
    { id: "428", date: "2017-01-24" },
    { id: "526", date: "2022-01-01" },
    { id: "428", name: "George" },
    { id: "526", name: "Sam" },
    { id: "827", name: "Dan" },
];
    
const result = data.reduce((accumulator, o) => {
    accumulator[o.id] = { ...accumulator[o.id] , ...o } || o;
        
    return accumulator;
}, {});
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Was just answering the same, but began to wonder what the OP means.  Is `result` here just like the accumulator variable the OP wants to do away with?  How about the literal `accumulator` in reduce?  But I think this is as correct as can be hoped for.

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce the dataset using `Array.prototype.reduce`. Just find the previous object by the `id` key in the accumulator (`acc`) or use a new object, and spread the current object over it.

```js
const data = [
  { id: "428", date: "2017-01-24" },
  { id: "526", date: "2022-01-01" },
  { id: "428", name: "George" },
  { id: "526", name: "Sam" },
  { id: "827", name: "Dan" }
];

const reduceBy = (data, predicate) =>
  data.reduce((acc, obj) =>
    (key => ({
      ...acc,
      [key]: {
        ...(acc[key] ?? {}),
        ...obj
      }
    }))
    (typeof predicate === 'string'
      ? obj[predicate]
      : predicate(obj)
    ), {});

const reducedData = reduceBy(data, ({ id }) => id); // or reduceBy(data, 'id')

console.log(reducedData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```